# Open OneSignal URL to WebView of another activity

Tags: android, onesignal

With OneSignal Notification, I'm sending a notification containing URL. In my `ADDITIONAL DATA` section, I'm sending `KEY: openURL` and `VALUE: http://example.com`.

I'm trying to open the link inside the `WebView` of my `DailyDose` activity.

Here, my `ProfileActivity` activity, I'm trying to recieves the notification and send it to `DailyDose` activity.

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenHandler())
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();
    }

    class NotificationOpenHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String openURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("openURL");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyDose.class);
            intent.putExtra("openURL", openURL);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `DailyDose` activity, where I'm trying to open the link inside the WebView:

```
public class DailyDose extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_dose);

            String openURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("openURL");

            final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.debug_view);
            textView.setText("URL from additionalData: " + openURL);

            WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            if (openURL == null)
                webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
            else
                webView.loadUrl(openURL);
```

But it's not working. Tapping on the notification, it just opens the `ProfileActivity` activity of the app. Doesn't do anything else. What am I doing wrong? I have been searching for a solution for a while but couldn't get anything that works. Will very much appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Is your implementation of `NotificationOpenHandler` called when tapping on the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the notification it opens the ProfileActivity because it is default behaviour of onesignal. It will open same activity that have initialization of onesignal. So first you need to disable this default behaviour of onesignal. Write below lines in your AndroidManifest file.

```
<application>
   <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"  android:value="DISABLE" />
</application>
```

Now run your project and check it will open DailyDose activity. Let me know if still you face any problems.

For more clarification on this please read onesignal's official document :

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding (Search : "Changing the open action of a notification" in the page).